# NBuilder start integer at 0

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nbuilder

I have this model:

```
public class OrderProperty
{
    [Required] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

The `Order` property starts at 0 instead of 1.
When I use **NBuilder** to build me a list of OrderProperties, it automatically sets the first `Order` to 1

```
Builder<OrderProperty>.CreateListOfSize(10).Build().ToList()
```

Is there a way to tell it to start from 0 instead?

Comment: The docs recommend you read the [tests](https://github.com/garethdown44/nbuilder/blob/master/Source/FizzWare.NBuilder.FunctionalTests/ListBuilderTests.cs), the tests suggest that something like `.TheFirst(1).With(x => x.Order = 0)` should work. (Disclaimer, ironically or otherwise: not tested.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do simply like this.

```
Builder<OrderProperty>.CreateListOfSize(10).All().With(x => x.Order -=1).Build().ToList();
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it for "TheFirst" and "TheNext" also? I tried: `Builder<TestOrderModel>.CreateListOfSize(10).All().TheFirst(5).With(m => m.CategoryId = "A").With(m => m.Order -= 1).TheNext(5).With(m => m.CategoryId = "B").With(m => m.Order -= 1).Build().ToList()` but it didn't work